# How to disable auto comment in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, comments

I do not want these comments when I create a new main class.

```
// TODO code application logic here 
/** 
* @param args the command line arguments 
*/ 

/** 
* 
* @author user 
*/
```

etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are unhappy with autogenerated comments in Java Class:

- `Tools -> Templates -> Java -> Java Class -> Open in Editor` -> delete
  what you do not like and save

You can leave just this:

```
<#if package?? && package != "">
package ${package};

</#if>
public class ${name} {

}
```

Comment: Netbeans 8.1 is the same.

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 also same.

Answer (score 1):

The place to configure it is `Tools -> Templates`.

Take a look at `Licenses/Default License`. If your project does not have an license, this is what will be on the begin of the file.

Answer (score 1):

in Tools->Templates->Java-> (edit template for both java Class and Java main Class) to the following:

```
<#if package?? && package != "">
package ${package};
</#if>

public class ${name} {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```